# Where is the GNOME virtual keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, keyboard, gnome3, accessibility

I use GNOME 3.36 on Arch Linux and even if *control panel* shows up the right option activated (see the screenshot below); none virtual keyboard is shown when needed i.e. on an input box like the search box on the upper-left corner.
[image]

How can I have an onscreen-keyboard?
Do I need any external package?

---

*journalctl does not show any error/warning switching off/on the setting*

Comment: IIRC the software is called caribou. Is it installed?

Comment: thanks @muru it was not installed on my system

Comment: since `caribou` looks buggy (i.e. I can't use it on all apps) are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @muru,
I solved this issue by installing the *caribou* package